# Stubbing a method thats called after a user is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to stub a method that lies in the code:

```
def create
  @user = Xaaron::User.new(user_signup_params)
  if save_new_user(@user)
    user = User.find(@user.first_name.parameterize)
    user_info_to_publish = {user_name: user.user_name, first_name: user.first_name, auth_token: user.auth_token, email: user.email}
    response = Xaaron::Publishers::Users.publish_new_user(user_info_to_publish)

    if response == 200
      user.set_published_user(true, false, 'create')
      redirect_to login_path
    else
      user.set_published_user(false, true, 'create')
      flash[:error] = 'Something went wrong in publishing your information to the applications you can interact with. We are aware of the issue and are on it.'
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

The method in question is `Xaaron::Publishers::Users.publish_new_user(user_info_to_publish)` I need to stub this method so I can check to make sure that things are working as I expect them to.

The test In question is:

```
it "should create a new user" do
  expect(Xaaron::Publishers::Users).to receive(:publish_new_user).with(
    {first_name: @user.first_name, user_name: 'johnq', email: @user.email, auth_token: @user.auth_token}
  ).and_return nil

  post :create, user: {
    first_name: @user.first_name, user_name: 'johnq',
    email: @user.email, email_confirmation: @user.email,
    password: 'SamplePassword', password_confirmation: 'SamplePassword'
  }

  expect(response).to redirect_to login_path
end
```

This test will fail because of one thing, the `auth_token`. I have it set to be generated Before the user is set in the database. The `@user` is done via: `@user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)`

How would I change my test so that it passes?

## Update

I should have included this:

The test is failing because:

```
  Xaaron::Publishers::Users received :publish_new_user with unexpected arguments
         expected: ({:first_name=>"Adam", :user_name=>"johnq", :email=>"user72@example.com"})
              got: ({:user_name=>"johnq", :first_name=>"Adam", :auth_token=>"KrGN3zu3kQJQdyh8JHl_XA", :email=>"user72@example.com", :auth_token=>nil})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I understanding right that the problem is that the auth_token you have available in the spec is not the one being used to make the Xaaron call?  If so you could change the spec to only check for some of the arguments.  That is, check for everything except auth_token.

```
expect(Xaaron::Publishers::Users).to receive(:publish_new_user).with(
  hash_including(first_name: @user.first_name, user_name: 'johnq', 
                 email: @user.email)).and_return nil
```

See: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames#Argument_Matchers

Comment: I didn't know you could check for some arguments. and its that the auth_token in the test is not set till after the user is actually created via the post request. but this idea should work